# Merge fails with DB Constraint violation

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts

When merging 2 contacts this error appears however when the contact is checked the merge has succeeded:

```
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "DB Error: constraint violation"
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#1782
    #message: "DB Error: constraint violation"
    #code: -3
    #file: "/var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php"
    #line: 138
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    -errorData: array:8 [
      "error_code" => -3
      "sql" => "INSERT INTO `civicrm_activity` (`activity_type_id` , `subject` , `activity_date_time` , `status_id` , `priority_id` , `parent_id` ) VALUES ( 54 , 'Contact ID 11170 has been merged into Contact ID 41737 and deleted.' ,  20231214131919 ,  2 ,  2 ,  202919 ) "
      "debug_info" => "INSERT INTO `civicrm_activity` (`activity_type_id` , `subject` , `activity_date_time` , `status_id` , `priority_id` , `parent_id` ) VALUES ( 54 , 'Contact ID 11170 has been merged into Contact ID 41737 and deleted.' ,  20231214131919 ,  2 ,  2 ,  202919 )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xxx.xxx`.`civicrm_activity`, CONSTRAINT `civicrm_activity_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_activity_fudge` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL)]"
      "entity" => "Activity"
      "action" => "create"
      "is_error" => 1
      "error_message" => "DB Error: constraint violation"
      "debug_information" => "INSERT INTO `civicrm_activity` (`activity_type_id` , `subject` , `activity_date_time` , `status_id` , `priority_id` , `parent_id` ) VALUES ( 54 , 'Contact ID 11170 has been merged into Contact ID 41737 and deleted.' ,  20231214131919 ,  2 ,  2 ,  202919 ) "
    ]
    trace: {
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php:138 {
        civicrm_api3(string $entity, string $action, array $params = [])
        › if (is_array($result) && !empty($result['is_error'])) {
        ›   throw new CRM_Core_Exception($result['error_message'], $result['error_code'] ?? 'undefined', $result);
        › }
      }
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php:2188 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php:2104 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Merge.php:324 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:622 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php:144 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php:43 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php:98 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:295 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:121 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:40 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/libraries/src/Dispatcher/LegacyComponentDispatcher.php:71 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/libraries/src/Dispatcher/LegacyComponentDispatcher.php:73 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:361 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:143 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:186 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:293 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/includes/app.php:61 { …}
      /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/httpdocs/administrator/index.php:32 { …}
```

Running CiviCRM 5.68 , PHP 8.1 , Joomla 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`xxx.xxx`.`civicrm_activity`, CONSTRAINT `civicrm_activity_ibfk_3` 
FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_activity_fudge` 
(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL)]
```

you may want to check the `civicrm_activity` table structure, discover where the `civicrm_activity_fudge` has come from and edit or remove this reference.

Answer (score 0):

Run below query

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_activity_contact DROP FOREIGN KEY civicrm_activity_ibfk_3;

ALTER TABLE civicrm_activity_contact 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_activity_contact_activity_id` FOREIGN KEY (`activity_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_activity` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Note: Take db backup before running query